# Mute one channel of audio

Tags: c++, audio, wav, waveform

I am dealing with audio data in the form of floats.

I would like to know if there is a way to mute a channel (the left or the right one) with a simply command, like just setting each second float to 0 or so. :-)

Thank you.

Comment: What does "singles" mean in your context?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say "floats".

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work or not?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. It was just a crazy idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend (completely) on the form in which your data is encoded.

If (and pretty much, *only* if) it's encoded as raw samples interleaved by channels, then yes, you can probably mute a channel by replacing its samples with zeros.

There are, however, lots of alternatives to that format. Just for one example, you could send L+R as one set of samples, and L-R as the other set of samples. In a case like this, you'd need to decode the channels from the data (L+R + L-R => L, L + R - L - R => R), zero the samples for one channel, then combine the result back to the same format.

Of course, a lot of formats are substantially more complex than even that. Compression like MP3 is considerably more complex with regard to encoding a single channel *and* allows you to encode the channels separately or as something like a sum and difference (which will usually save some space).

Comment: Could you perhaps include a pseudo code that includes modulo? I think this would also help less experienced people such as me. Thank you!

Comment: @tmighty: I suppose you'd use modulo to determine whether you're on the sample you want to zero, something like `result = sample_number % 2 == 0 ? input : 0;`